# If a person invests money, and then invest his monthly income of that investment every month, which is the total amount earned?

Tags: matlab, math, finance

Let's say I invest 1000€ and excpect to gain +10% in a year, therefore 1100.
And the income of every monthh, which is 91.667, I invest it again, every month, plus the 10% of that 91.667, the extra interest.

Is the following algorithm correct?

```
totalMoney=1100;
moneyPerMonth=0;
for i=1:12
moneyPerMonth=(moneyPerMonth+totalMoney)/12
totalMoney=totalMoney+moneyPerMonth/12
end
```

I get the following results:

```
moneyPerMonth =  91.667
totalMoney =  1107.6
moneyPerMonth =  99.942
totalMoney =  1116.0
moneyPerMonth =  101.33
totalMoney =  1124.4
moneyPerMonth =  102.14
totalMoney =  1132.9
moneyPerMonth =  102.92
totalMoney =  1141.5
moneyPerMonth =  103.70
totalMoney =  1150.1
moneyPerMonth =  104.49
totalMoney =  1158.8
moneyPerMonth =  105.28
totalMoney =  1167.6
moneyPerMonth =  106.08
totalMoney =  1176.5
moneyPerMonth =  106.88
totalMoney =  1185.4
moneyPerMonth =  107.69
totalMoney =  1194.3
moneyPerMonth =  108.50
totalMoney =  1203.4
```

Which means that I find that I increase the income from +10% to 20,034% with total earning of 1203.4.

Is that correct?

Comment: "I invest 1000€", this means that you should start your program with `totalMoney=1000;`, no? Why do you start with the money you expect to have at the end of the year?

Comment: I start with the total money I will get back, because I divide it with 12, so I have the monthly income.

Comment: If the interest rate is 10% per year, then you get 10/12=8.33% per month. So you multiply by 1.0833 every month. At the end of the year you have `1000*1.0833^12`.

Comment: When you say you expect to gain +10%, do you mean that is your annual interest rate (APR)? Is this simple or compounding interest? The first statement makes it seem you expect to gain 10% on the principal.

Comment: You're either going to project how much you're going to earn depending on the interest rate or you're trying to determine your initial investment if you've earned 1100 at the end. Or possibly to figure out the interest rate. This question should not include 1000, 1100 and 10% all in the same question. You need two of the three and then you can solve for the remaining parameter.

Comment: Or you're finding the monthly amount which you have at `91.667` if it's simple interest. Simple interest will cause a fixed amount dependent on the principal. Compound interest will accumulate as be calculated based on the previous month.

Comment: There are lots of online calculators for simple and compound interest You can check your work at the following link. Any solution you come up with should match: https://www.investor.gov/financial-tools-calculators/calculators/compound-interest-calculator

Comment: But this calculator doesn't support variable amount of money to contribute every month.

Comment: @DIMITRIOSKOUMANDRAKIS Every month there will be an additional contribution of `91.667` does this start at the beginning of the 2nd month? Does this contribution graph match what you're trying to explain? https://github.com/MichaelTr7/StackOverflow/tree/master/Cash%20Flow

Answer (score 0):

Two things: First, you're not clear in your question about the compounding - if the 10% figure is compounded annually, at the end of the year you will indeed have 1,100, but your monthly interest rate is not going to be `0.1/12`or `0.008333`. If you use that figure for the monthly calculations, you'll be compounding your interest monthly, which results in an effective annual rate of `10.471%`, not 10%. To get to an effective 10% annual rate, your monthly interest rate is only `0.007974`.

Once you decide which one you want to use, the rest is fairly simple. Using, for example, python:

```
annual =  0.007974 #the code below uses this rate, but you can easily change it to "monthly"
monthly = 0.008333
months = 12
investment = 1000

balance = investment
print('after month',"\taccrued int","\tbalance",)
for m in range(months):    
    interest = balance*annual
    balance+=interest    
    print(m+1, '\t\t',format(interest,".2f"), '\t\t',format(balance,".2f"))
```

Output:

```
after month accrued int balance
1        7.97        1007.97
2        8.04        1016.01
3        8.10        1024.11
4        8.17        1032.28
5        8.23        1040.51
6        8.30        1048.81
7        8.36        1057.17
8        8.43        1065.60
9        8.50        1074.10
10       8.56        1082.66
11       8.63        1091.30
12       8.70        1100.00
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, because it displays the monthly balance.
My question is, what if I invest again the monthly earnings.
And I think that when I invest, I spend the amount of money invested, for example 1000, and then I get 1000/12 + 1000*0.01/12 every month.

Comment: @DIMITRIOSKOUMANDRAKIS If you look at the code, you will see that the earnings from each month are reinvested and earn interest again the following month.

Comment: Yes, but you end up with 1100, which is the amount without the extra investing.
This is if you invest 1000 with 10% interest and you get the monthly earning without reinvesting it.

Comment: @DIMITRIOSKOUMANDRAKIS No; it's a function of how compounding is supposed to be calculated. Run the code with `monthly` instead of `annual` and you'll get a different number; that's why they are both there.